# Adding a user to Azure AD group via graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am following the microsoft docs on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0. My goal is to use the graph api to add a user to a specific group. When I make the request

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/members/$ref
```

With a body of

```
{"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{user-id}"}
```

I get the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-08T00:14:25",
      "request-id": "bcc05c0f-8195-4744-8736-bd30586a7663"
    }
  }
}
```

What needs to be added to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the document of [`Add member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0), we need one of the following permission in `scope`:

[image]

Please navigate to your application -> API permission in the portal. Add one of the permissions of Microsoft Graph, and grant admin consent for your tenant.

If you use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), you need to add application permission. Delegated permission is suitable for other flows.

Comment: btw I was able to get this to work with just `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All` Thank you for the help!